# Is there a way to tell what slapd.conf file slapd is using?

Tags: openldap

My config file passes the slaptest but when I try to do a ldapsearch it throws back an Invalid Credentials. How do I tell which file it is using, and more importantly. How do I specify which one to use?

Comment: On a Linux system you might try `ps -eaf | grep slapd` and look to see what the argument to the `-F` option is. That argument is the directory containing the slapd configuration file.

Comment: @rlandster Thankyou.